# SmoothDivScroll clickable item

Tags: jquery, ipad, click, touch

I am using smoothdivscroll plugin for a thumbnail functionality in my site. Everything works great in desktop browser except for iPad browser (i have not tested yet in iphone browser). This my javascript code :

```
$("div#thumbScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
  hotSpotScrolling: false,
  touchScrolling: true,
  manualContinuousScrolling: true,
  mousewheelScrolling: false,
  //visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "",
  //hotSpotScrolling: false,
  //visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "",
  //mousewheelScrollingStep: 45,
  //mousewheelScrolling: "vertical",
  //touchScrolling: true
  scrollToAnimationDuration: 500,
  setupComplete : function() {

  }
});
```

When viewing in ipad, the user can scroll via touching and dragging/swiping fingers and it works well. However i attached a jquery click event on the smoothdivscroll ITEM but it isnt triggered. I have it like this

```
 $(document).on('click', "div#thumbScrollable .clickableitem", function(event) { 
    alert("SMOOTHDIVSCROLL ITEM IS CLICKED");
 });
```

When i clicked the item, an alert box is not shown and this means that the event is not triggered. I am guessing that there's a clash between the TOUCH and CLICK event thats why jquery could not detect if its a click event. Anyone have this problems before?

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "div#thumbScrollable" ).bind("touchstart",function( event ) {
    $("div#thumbScrollable").smoothDivScroll("enable");
    });
    $( "div#thumbScrollable" ).on('touchend',function( event ) {
    $("div#thumbScrollable").smoothDivScroll("disable");
    });
```

You have to disable smooth scroll after the touch scrolling and reenable when touch start or touch move.

Comment: we need the explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

how about assigning the handler to `mousedown` and `touchstart`?

```
$(document).on('mousedown touchstart', "div#thumbScrollable .clickableitem", function(event) { 
    alert("SMOOTHDIVSCROLL ITEM IS CLICKED");
});
```